Taire mal à quelqu'un
Mauriac, "Le Désert de l'amour" :

Sa maison n'était plus qu'à demi pleine et les chambres vide lui taisaient mal.

Au début j'y ai lu "n'arrivaient pas de lui donner la paix" ou quelque chose comme ça, mais je n'arrive pas à trouver une acceptation de "taire" qui prendrait un COI. Serait-ce une simple faute de frappe pour "faisaient" ou est-ce que j'ai manqué quelque chose en cherchant ? Édition : Livre de poche ...


C'est un t? Pas un f? taire mal: inconnu. faire mal: pas de problème.

@Frank See edit. Definitely a typo :/ The reason I doubted was (a) because it is about her complaining, so I thought maybe it did a poor job of giving her peace / quiet, and (b) "the empty rooms hurt her" is somewhat of a poetic idea. But on reflection I guess it could just mean "were bad for her / did her no good", which makes more sense... Is that how you'd read it?

It looks like a typo. The verb is written faisaient in this Grasset edition printed in 1970:

Faire mal makes more sense than taire mal in this sentence, (he was hurt by the empty rooms) although taisaient might still be explainable (the empty rooms couldn't hide him the fact that the house was only half full). I would have nevertheless expected [...] le lui taisaient mal in that case though.

Merci ! « The wicked perceive new usages where none exist » ...
